# Как поменять стили у .parent().parent() jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
Не получается достучаться до дедушки, что я делаю не так?
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $(function() {
      if ($('#bitum').hasClass('.active')) {
          $(this).parents().eq(2).css("background", "red");
      } else if ($('#it').hasClass('.active')) {
          $(this).parents().eq(2).css("background", "red");
      } else if ($('#energetic').hasClass('.active')) {
          $(this).parents().eq(2).css("background", "red");
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.tabs__wrap {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="tabs__wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="tabs__caption">
        <li class="tabs__item active" id="bitum">
          <p>Item 1</p>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs__item" id="energetic">
          <p>Item 2</p>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs__item" id="it">
          <p>Item 3</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `closest("li")` используйте вместо `parents().eq(2)`

Comment: Не, такой вариант не срабатывает

Answer (score 0):

1. уберите вложенность `document.ready` и `$(function(){ .. } )` это одно и то же.
2. `hasClass()` в качестве параметра должен получить чистое имя класса без точки
3. вы проверяете `$("#bitum").hasClass()`, а поиск выполняете у `$(this)` , то есть у самого документа, а не того же `$("#bitum")`
4. указание номера в коллекции родителей сломается, когда структура DOM изменится. Используйте `closest()`
5. заверните все if-ы в цикл, если действия все равно одинаковы.
6. генерите это все на стороне сервера, а не клиента

```js
$(function() {
      if ($('#bitum').hasClass('active')) {
          $("#bitum").closest("li")
                     .css("background-color", "red");
      } 
      else if ($('#it').hasClass('.active')) {
          $("#it").closest("li")
                  .css("background", "red");
      } 
      else if ($('#energetic').hasClass('.active')) {
          $("#energetic").closest("li")
                    .css("background", "red");
      }
  });
```

```css
.tabs__wrap {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="tabs__wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="tabs__caption">
        <li class="tabs__item active" id="bitum">
          <p>Item 1</p>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs__item" id="energetic">
          <p>Item 2</p>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs__item" id="it">
          <p>Item 3</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
$(function() {
    var items = ['#bitum', '#it', 'energetic'];
    items.forEach(function(id, k){
        if($(id).hasClass('active')){
           $(id).closest("li").css("background-color", "red");
        } 
     });     
});
```

Comment: Дело в том, что данный код меняет стили непосредственно `li`, а мне нужно для `tabs__wrap`

Comment: @max ну сделайте `closest(".tabs__wrap")` или `parents(".tab__wrap")`